# Multiple optional parameters not working on laravel 5.3 route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

I have the below route in web.php the first route works always but the second one doesn't if i use the url like

```
ads/mobiles
```

then function check_if_category executes fine. But i use url like

```
ads/lahore/mobiles
```

in this case it redirects to the 404 page.

```
Route::get('ads/all', 'AdControllerWithoutAuth@all_ads')->name('route_all_ads');
Route::get('ads/{location?}{category?}{keyword?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
```

I have also worked like this

```
Route::get('ads/all', 'AdControllerWithoutAuth@all_ads')->name('route_all_ads');
//Route::get('ads/{location?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
//Route::get('ads/{location?}{category?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
Route::get('ads/{location?}{category?}{keyword?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
```

but no success. Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `/` between these parameters or Laravel will see these as one long string.

```
Route::get('ads/{location?}/{category?}/{keyword?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
```

Comment: Glad I could help, consider marking this as the solution to your question so other users might find this as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `/` to the route URI:

```
Route::get('ads/{location?}/{category?}/{keyword?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
```

Answer (score 1):

use `separator`

```
Route::get('ads/{location?}/{category?}/{keyword?}', 'Categories@check_if_category')->name('route_f_category_page');
```